# Linux snap automatic start differs from manual start

Tags: startup

I have WhatsDesk installed on my Ubuntu 18.4 system. When I start it manually, the application picks up the settings correctly and starts with displaying my Whatsapp info. On the other hand, when I put Whatsdesk into the list of automatically started applications, it starts but not with the configured settings.

How can parameters be set that WhatsDesk finds my settings? Is this an issue related to WhatsDesk only or to all snaps?

Thanks for your help!

**UPDATE**

In the meantime, I accepted to start Whatsdesk like it asked me. I now have two whatsdesk folders: `~/snap/whatsdesk` and `~/.config/whatsdesk`. The first one seems like the older one, although there are some files and links dated today. The `.config` folder seems to contain the active settings.

Comment: Sorry that I posted in the wrong site...

Comment: @Amanda: you left at least two lowercase d-s ... Very important also... Sheesh.

Comment: I was mostly aiming to make the directory names readable. I'm not actually that stressed out about CamelCase naming.